# Google Maps in Jetpack Compose Freezes

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

When triggering a navigation within onInfoWindowClick, my app freezes. At this point in my build, I have navigated to different composables countless times so this code should work.

```
GoogleMap(
               modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
               cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
               properties = mapProperties
           ) {
               testData.forEach { contact ->


                   var latlngFinal = LatLng(0.0, 0.0)
                   val coder = Geocoder(LocalContext.current)
                   try {
                       val addresses: ArrayList<Address> = coder.getFromLocationName(contact.address, 50) as ArrayList<Address>
                       for (add in addresses) {
                           latlngFinal = LatLng(add.latitude, add.longitude)
                       }
                   } catch (e: IOException) {
                       e.printStackTrace()
                   }

                   val markerState = rememberMarkerState(null, latlngFinal)

                   Marker(
                       state = markerState,
                       title = contact.title,
                       snippet = contact.description,
                       onInfoWindowClick = {
                           navController?.currentBackStackEntry?.arguments?.putSerializable(
                               "contact_object",
                               userJson
                           )
                           navController?.navigate(route = Routes.RecruitersInAreaDetail.route)
                       }
                   )
                   builder.include(latlngFinal)

               }

               cameraPositionState.move(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 64))

           }
```

Comment: I am also having the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Comment: I solved this as below. I'm not sure if it's an ideal solution. That's why I'm posting as a comment.

val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

 onInfoWindowClick = {
                            scope.launch {
                                 //navigation here
                            }
                        }

Comment: Thank you! I ll update my comment if this doesnt work

Comment: Seems that those callbacks are invoked from another thread or are suspend. The workaround I also found was to run the method body inside a coroutine

Answer (score 0):

Your app freezes because your are calling `coder.getFromLocationName` inside a foreach loop from your UI thread. As per documentation, this call will block your UI thread:

http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int)

You should move `coder.getFromLocationName` this inside your viewModel like below:

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val addresses: ArrayList<Address> = coder.getFromLocationName(contact.address, 50) as ArrayList<Address>
        } catch (exception: IOException) {
            Log.i("RegistrationScreen", "setAddress IOException")
        }
    }
```